# GetType().GetMethods returns no methods when using a BindingFlag

Tags: c#, reflection

So I am trying to retrieve all private methods in my class that have a specific attribute.  When I do

```
this.GetType().GetMethods()
```

This returns 18 methods, all of which are public.  So I tried to modify it to use Binding flags like:

```
this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

This causes zero results to come back.  I then started playing around and I can't get any overrides of `GetMethods(BindingFlags.x)` to work.

```
this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Default);
this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
```

All of those return zero results.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should pass [BindingFlags.Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) in order to match instance methods:

```
this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

You can also add `BindingFlags.Static` to the flags if you want both instance and static methods.